# addpoint is not adding point in highcharts ,where data is updated dynamically with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, highcharts

my task is to add  multiple series dynamically and update series data dynamically.
my data is loaded with ajax request.

i have used the logic given on highcharts side to update the data dynamically. but addpoint is not adding points to series dont know why, when i checked the series object, it has data but dirtyfiled is set to true (dont know the reason)

code given below is used to load data dynamically. here problem is add point, it is not adding data to graph. 
series object is showing isDirty :true
                         isDirtyData:true.

i think this isDirty has something to deal with.  please help me out. facing this problem for quite a long time .

```
from_date=new Date().getTime()-60000;
        function requestData ()
                          {
                              console.log("into request data")
                              console.log(TypeOfParameter,sub_type,sub_type_parameter,hostname,from_date)
                              $.ajax({
                                  url:serverUrl+'/api/fetch_params/',
                                  type:'GET',


                                  data:{'type':TypeOfParameter,'sub-type':sub_type,'hostname':hostname,'param':sub_type_parameter,'from-date':from_date},
                                  success:function(response)
                                  {
                                   console.log("into success")
                                  var id=sub_type+sub_type_parameter
                                  var series = chart.get(id)

                                  shift = series.data.length > 150; // shift if the series is longer than 300 (drop oldest point)
                                   console.log(shift)
                                      response= $.parseJSON(response)

                                      var x=sub_type;
                                      all_data=response.response.data[x]
                                      itemdata=[]//
                                      console.log(all_data.length)
                                      //console.log(new Date(all_data[all_data.length-1][0]),'latest timestamp')
                                      from_date=all_data[all_data.length-1][0]
//                                      series.addPoint(all_data,false,shift);
                                       console.log("series name:",series.data.length,series.name)
                                      for (var i = 0; i < all_data.length; i++)
                                      {
                                         console.log(all_data[i][0],all_data[i][1]);
                                          series.addPoint({ x: all_data[i][0],y: all_data[i][1],id: i},false,shift);
                                      }
                                      console.log(series,"object")
                                      console.log("hey",series.data.length)
                                      console.log("hey",series.data.length )
                                      console.log(series.data)
                                       console.log("out of success")
                                      //chart.redraw();

                                  setTimeout(requestData, 60000);


                                  },
                                  cache:false,
                                  error:function()
                                  {
                                      console.log("err")

                                  }

                              });
                            console.log("out of request ")

                          }
```

below functin is used to draw highchart,here onload event is used to load data dynamically.

```
                       $(function (

) {
                               console.log("into highcharts")
                                 chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                        chart: {
                            renderTo: 'container',
                            defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
                            events: {
                                load: requestData
                            }
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: 'cpu Usage'
                        },
                        xAxis: {
                            type: 'datetime',
                            tickPixelInterval: 150,
                            maxZoom: 20 * 1000
                        },
                        yAxis: {
                            minPadding: 0.2,
                            maxPadding: 0.2,
                            title: {
                                text: 'Value',
                                margin: 80
                            }
                        },
                        series: [{
                            id:sub_type+sub_type_parameter,
                            name: 'CPU',
                            data: []
                        }]
    });;
                               console.log("out of highcharts")
                             });



chart = $('#container').highcharts();
```

this is the code to add axis dynamically.

```
        var flag=true
                if(TypeOfParameter=='cpu'&&flag)
                {
                    console.log("entering into cpu",sub_type,flag)
//                    all_data = response.response.data[sub_type]
//                    itemdata=[]
//                    for(i in all_data)
//                    {
//                        itemdata.push(all_data[i][1])
//                    }
//                    console.log(itemdata[0])
//                    console.log("Drawing trend")


                     chart.addAxis({ // Primary yAxis

                              id:'Cpu_axis'+sub_type_parameter,
                              labels: {
                                  formatter: function() {
                                      return this.value;
                                  },
                                  style: {
                                      color: '#89A54E'
                                      }
                              },
                              title: {
                                  text: "core "+ sub_type+ " "+sub_type_parameter,
                                  style: {
                                      color: '#89A54E'
                                  }
                              },

                            lineWidth: 1,
                            lineColor: '#08F'

                          });


                    chart.addSeries({
                            id:sub_type+sub_type_parameter,
                            name: "core "+sub_type+" "+sub_type_parameter,
                            data:[],
                            tooltip: {
                                valueSuffix: ' q    %'
                                    },
                                 yAxis:'Cpu_axis'+sub_type_parameter
                                })
                              //chart.redraw();
                    flag=false

                    console.log("returning from cpu")

                    }
```

Comment: did you found any solution ? I'm also having same issue, points are added sometimes, but most times blank candles appear. http://jsfiddle.net/nitincool4urchat/3v61f8v7/12/

Answer (score 1):

I can see it is old question of 2013 year. But there are my thoughts for other guys that look for the answer on this question now.

There is highcharts.js bug https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/3452. In short the bug description is: when point is added with addPoint() method to chart series then this new point doesn't appear in someSerie.data array.

I propose following workaround for this issue "new points aren't present in someSerie.data array" :

```
// after adding new point with addPoint() method
let min = chart.xAxis[0].getExtremes().min;
let max = chart.xAxis[0].getExtremes().max;
chart.zoomOut();
chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(min, max);
```

After that following check :

```
if(series.data.length) { 
    chart.redraw(); 
}
```

should work OK.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's about how you are using `addPoint()` function:

```
 series.addPoint({ x: all_data[i][0],y: all_data[i][1],id: i},false,shift);
```

You have set redraw = false, so it won't redraw chart. Set it to true, and will work.

More about: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.addPoint()

Comment: hey i have set it to false intentionally, setting it to true hang my browser, reason which i figured out was there was no data to redraw and it keeps calling it.
i am checking data after each ajax request, it is empty list. kindly help.

Comment: Right, so why did you disabled redraw() ? Here: `//chart.redraw();` Can I see it 'live'?

Comment: hi i have disabled to check if data is added to chart or not, if i enable it , browser get hanged. here is my full code.

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/shivnarayans/L8nxN/)

i am stuck on this for quite a long time. please help its quite urgent. i am not able to figure out the reason for series.addpont() not working.

Comment: Putting this code into not working jsFiddle isn't helpful.. I mean live site or something similar.

Comment: i can not put live link as i am working on localhost. there are few files which are included locally at the moment.
can you please tell me the reason for addpoint not adding point.
i have seen series object, it has xdata and ydata processed. but there is nothing in data[] field. and also isDirt:true and isDirtydata:true are set, while in other series these two filed are set to false. what is the reason for isDirty field. do i need to check my logic or do i have some issue with highchart things ?

Comment: The adding point is not adding point because you are not redrawing chart. Use chart.redraw(). If it is hanging your browser that means you are doing something wrong. Maybe you have points with the same timestamp, or data isn't sorted ascending?

Comment: thanx for quick reply u have been a big help. i have checked timestamp for each point . it is different. i dont know the reason for it. if you can dare to read full code, please do so. i may have done some logical mistake which i am not able to point out.

i have tried it by inserting only y values ,also i put a check on redraw
if(series.data.length)
                        chart.redraw();
here i am facing a very random issue. series.data.length is zero for quite a long time and then  points are added after several iteration.this is quite random. but good news is chart is drawn.

Comment: I have read your code, but I don't see anything wrong (only the same as in a second SO question). Post your AJAX response example, maybe there is something wrong.

Comment: hey ajax response request is giving me data perfectly fine. initially i was acceding series by chart.get(id) , but when  i accesed it by series index, like series[0] it worked. here problem with me is , there will be multiple series over here, i cant access series by its index everytime. so can you suggest me hack to fix it.

Comment: Add to each series unique ID, so you would get series vie get(ID). This line isn't working: `id:sub_type+sub_type_parameter,` ?